# EvaluationMonitor and variables with indices + subscripts

Tags: numerics, evaluation

I have encountered the following problem while using `EvaluationMonitor` with `NMinimize`: variables that have both a subscript and an index, e.g. `Subscript[x,y][1]` do not evaluate when part of another expression. Why is that and can this be overcome except by renaming all variables?

Here is an MWE:

```
f=x^2;cons={x^2<1};vars={x};
Reap[NMinimize[{f,cons},vars,MaxIterations->1,EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[f]]]

f=Subscript[x, y][1]^2;cons={Subscript[x, y][1]^2<1};vars={Subscript[x, y][1]};
Reap[NMinimize[{f,cons},vars,MaxIterations->1,EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[f]]]

f=Subscript[x, y][1]^2;cons={Subscript[x, y][1]^2<1};vars={Subscript[x, y][1]};
Reap[NMinimize[{f,cons},vars,MaxIterations->1,EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[Subscript[x, y][1]^2]]]
```

And the output:

```
{{5.55989*10^-17, {x -> -7.45647*10^-9}}, {{0.687328, 0.939632, 
   0.832435, 0.0023905, 0.843385, 0.872993, 0.86633, 0.333475, 
   0.93129, 0.842581, 0.687328, 0.842581, 0.0265738, 0.1642, 0.843385,
    0.18038, 1.03906, 0.333475, 0.0358687, 0.842581, 0.0023905, 
   0.0023905, 0.000600487, 0.0023905, 5.55989*10^-17, 5.55989*10^-17}}}

{{5.55989*10^-17, {Subscript[x, y][
     1] -> -7.45647*10^-9}}, {{Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, Subscript[x, y][1]^2, 
   Subscript[x, y][1]^2}}}

{{5.55989*10^-17, {Subscript[x, y][1] -> -7.45647*10^-9}}, {{0.687328,
    0.939632, 0.832435, 0.0023905, 0.843385, 0.872993, 0.86633, 
   0.333475, 0.93129, 0.842581, 0.687328, 0.842581, 0.0265738, 0.1642,
    0.843385, 0.18038, 1.03906, 0.333475, 0.0358687, 0.842581, 
   0.0023905, 0.0023905, 0.000600487, 0.0023905, 5.55989*10^-17, 
   5.55989*10^-17}}}
```

Thanks!

Edit: Wolfram has confirmed that this is a bug.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Just another reason to hate `Subscript`...